# Render partial view upon menu selection

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got a tab menu that I want to use to show different partial views depending on the menu item selection. This is how it looks like:

[image: page]

Something like: if the selected item is 1, then render view "whatever"...

I want to click on the 1st menu item and render the partial view for Tab1, the 2nd menu item and render the partial view for Tab2, etc...

**EDIT - what I have been trying**

The view:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="tab" id="tab1" href="#">Personal Data</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab" id="tab2" href="#">User Image</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab" id="tab3" href="#">Regional Definitions</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab" id="tab4" href="#">Colors and Themes</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab" id="tab5" href='#'>Personal Area</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="div-for-partial">

</div>

    ...

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('.tab').click(function () {
            var id = this.id;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetPartialView", "ConfigController")',
                data: { 'id': id },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#div-for-partial').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

The controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetPartialView(string id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case "tab1":
            return PartialView("_PersonalData");
        case "tab2":
            return PartialView("_UserImage");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Do you want to render Ajax loaded views when the tabs are clicked? (Tabs normally expect all partials, for all tabs, to be rendered with the page).

Comment: Ajaxing partial views is definitely the way to go and is quite simple once you get into it.

Comment: Just a thought, but will `data: 'id': id` map to the controller action? I thought `id` was only implied in the routing, so needs to be in the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing Ajax is not that complicated. First assign each of your tabs a unique ID and a common class.

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="tab" id="tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tab" id="tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tab" id="tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then, create a controller action to post to.

```
public ActionResult GetPartialView(string id)
{
    switch(id)
    {
        case "tab1":
            return PartialView("_PartialForTab1");
        case "tab2":
            return PartialView("_PartialForTab2");
        case "tab3":
            return PartialView("_PartialForTab3");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("YourHomePage");
}
```

Add a click event handler for your tabs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.tab').click(function() {
        var id = this.id;

        $.get('@Url.Content("GetPartialView")', { 'id': id },  function (data) { 
            $('#div-for-partial').html(data); 
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with last part of your answer: I've written the script you provided and adapted it to match the controller name, the div id, etc.. Now, how do I call this? Adding an `onClick` to each `li` doesn't work. Can you help me out?

Comment: Whoops, I'm sorry, mistyped the tab class selector, it's supposed to be $('.tab').click, I will update the answer.

Comment: nothing happens. No view is displayed: I placed a breakpoint on the controller but after clicking the tab it doesn't get hit

Comment: @chiapa: Did you wrap the JQuery code shown in a DOM ready handler (or place it at the very end of the body tag)?

Comment: Do you mean this? `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` I have this in the header of the `_Layout` page. If it's not this, help me please, I'm new to both Ajax and JQuery

Comment: I've updated my answer to show what @TrueBlueAussie is saying. Place the script block at the bottom of your view.

Comment: I've got that but nothing happens when I click the tabs

Comment: Can you post your entire view code and your controller action that you added for this?

Comment: @Josh, check my question: There's what I have so far

Comment: Place an alert inside the click function to see if its getting hit.
alert("Hit");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55991/discussion-between-josh-and-chiapa).